# What happens if I add 0.0.0.0 as a whitelisted IP?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip

Google search for 0.0.0.0 says that

> In the Internet Protocol Version 4, the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target. To give a special meaning to an otherwise invalid piece of data is an application of in-band signaling.

Which makes me wonder that if I add this IP address as whitelisted entry in the firewall, would it mean that the machine will be accessible to every network outside? Or will it only allow the requests originating from the machine itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RickyBeam pointed out, `0.0.0.0` is not a routable address. However, in access lists in firewalls it can be used with a netmask other than the implicit `/32` to indicate the entire IPv4 address space: `0.0.0.0/0`. In that case, any IPv4 address would match the condition.

Answer (score 2):

(This is more a security SE question)

In networking circles (like this one), you should never, *ever*, see a packet with zero as an address. Anyone sending "zero" across the internet is (a) broken, or (b) *trying to break something*.

A machine talking to itself will use a loopback address (eg. 127.0.0.1)